# fields alignment problem Css

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment

Hey this is my problem, i can not align tis input field with these images, they are in a div, i will paste the code below
[image: Image Of fields]

So what do you suggest should i do, stuck with this problem, need a quick answer plz

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;"> 

 <input type="text" id="queryInput" value="pizza" style="width: 180px; height:30px;border: 1px solid #d3d6d9;padding: 4px 10px 2px 10px;background-color: white;-moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -khtml-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;  font-size: 12px;   font-family: Droid Sans, Arial, sans-serif;"/> 
 <a href="javascript:doSearch()"><img src="img/search.png" /></a> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
 <a href="javascript:toggleStreetView()"><img src="img/street.png" /></a>
 <a href="javascript:toggleGoogleView()"><img src="img/google.png" /></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Need the the CSS as to know how they are aligned now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/K8rHG/

Comment: @theGame: You should use @ with the name for faster communication!

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
#queryInput {
    margin-top: -10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to align **boxes** vertically, one of the best methods are to make'em all **block box** (so they can accept width and height), then set the height of all of them to the highest box, then try to vertical-align contents in each box. In your special case, the height of search box is 30px. But as @Jawad said, you should include the CSS of the parent div, with CSS of other elements, so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 div input, div a{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:none;
    margin:0px;
    .display:inline;
    .zoom:1;
}
```

Comment: in this case it force for IE7 block element to inline-block

Answer (score 0):

1. try to avoid inline styles, yes?
2. vertically center the images, and they will align w the textbox:

   < style>
   div img { vertical-align:middle; }
   < / style>

http://jsfiddle.net/mSgVg/